# Whats the best practise on how to store json data from a custom settings page?

Tags: database, forms, options, json, settings-api

I'm creating my first Wordpress Plugin and want to let the user configure multiple urls which he can name and safe as "channels".

I've set up a settings page and wanted to store the data through `add_option()` as json like this:

```
[
{
    "name": "my first saved url",
    "url": "www.example.com"
},
{
    "name": "my second saved url",
    "url": "www.another-example.com"
}
]
```

I was considering json because there will be more values in the future than only these two.

I'd like to have just some input fields with name and url which i can validate and put together with existing ones and store them away.

By using the Settings-api from wordpress i have the feeling to be quite limited as far as the settings field correspond with only one option.

I also thought about not using the settings-api at all and just define a custom form with input fields and safe them in the end with `update_option()`.

Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve what i want?

my full code is below i'm happy for any thoughts..

```
class MySettingsPage{

public function __construct() {
add_action( 
  'admin_menu', 
  array( $this, 'init_settings_page' ) 
);

    add_action(
        'admin_init',
        array( &$this, 'init_settings' )
    );
}

public function init_settings_page(){

add_option( 'channels' );

$page_title = 'Settings channels';
$menu_title = 'Channels';
$capability = 'manage_options';
$slug = 'my_saved_urls';
$callback = array( $this, 'plugin_settings_page_content' );
$icon = 'dashicons-admin-plugins';
$position = 30.5;

add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $slug, $callback, $icon, $position );

}

public function plugin_settings_page_content() { ?>
<div class="wrap">
    <h2>Channels</h2>
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php
            settings_fields( 'my_saved_urls' );
            do_settings_sections( 'my_saved_urls' );
            submit_button();
        ?>
    </form>
</div> <?php
}

public function init_settings() {


    register_setting(
        'my_saved_urls',
        'urls_as_json',
        array(
            'type'                => 'string',
        )
    );

    add_settings_section(
        'urls_section_preview',
        'Configured channels',
        function () {
        },
        'my_saved_urls'
    );

    add_settings_field(
        'urls_as_json',
        'channel URLs',
        function () {
            echo '<input type="text" name="urls_as_json" value="' . get_option( 'urls_as_json' ) . '" 
 class="regular-text"/>';
        },
        'my_saved_urls',
        'urls_section_preview'
    );


}
}
```

Comment: Haven't worked with the settings API in some time, but doesn't WP just serialize arrays? So there should be no need to do the JSON yourself, it should automatically work already.

Comment: oh gosh.. you're right. this simplifys alot :D I could just pass the array to `update_option()` and thats it.. thanks!